# Thread.join() not working in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to create long-running application for performing various tasks on different threads. Each task should have one-minute timeout. Here is my implementation:

```
runner = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
   @Override
   public void run() {  }
       // some actions here
});
runner.start();
startJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();            
runner.join(TIMEOUT);    
stopJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();

if ((stopJoin - startJoin) >= TIMEOUT)
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout when reading the response from   process");
```

In general case it is working and throwing TimeoutExceptions, but sometimes it is doing nothing after even few hours. So the questions is if Thread.join is reliable on Android?

I have an idea to use Thread.wait and notify instead of that, what is the better way in your opinion?

Comment: Have you tried services?

Comment: `it is doing nothing after even few hours.` explain this? is the thread running still or has it ended?

Comment: "main" thread is running and waiting on join.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing all time base task using `Timer` and `TimerTask`. Check the following code and probably this should be useful to you:

```
Timer t =new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //The task you want to perform after the timeout period 
        }
    }, TIMEOUT);
```

**EDIT**

I am giving a try at solving your problem. I am using the code written by @amicngh as my base code and have done some modifications to it. I presume that after the `TIMEOUT` period you want to close the running thread. Check the following code runs fine and the explanation that follows:

```
public class ThreadTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final long TIMEOUT=100;
    final long startJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Thread runner = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        long stopJoin;
           @Override
           public void run() {
               try{
                   for(;;){
                       System.out.println("running "); 
                       stopJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();

                       if ((stopJoin - startJoin) >= TIMEOUT){
                         throw new Exception();  
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
               }

           }
               // some actions here
        });

    runner.start();

    synchronized (ThreadTest.class) {
        ThreadTest.class.wait(TIMEOUT);
    }


    /*if ((stopJoin - startJoin) >= TIMEOUT)
        try {
            throw new Exception("Timeout when reading the response from   process");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/


        System.out.println("Running Thread");

}
```

}

The Thread API description says that it is unsafe to `destroy` or `stop` (hence both these method has been deprecated) and one of the way to stop a thread is to throw an exception. Hence I am checking for the Timeout inside the `runner` thread. Now about making the Main thread wait it is done by the 2 lines of code which uses `synchronized` to synchronize the access to the thread.

Hope this code and explanation solves your problem.

Comment: I am familiar with Timer and TimerTask, but in this case I want to block the main thread, until operations from runner thread will be finished. I do not want to create additional thread here, because application already use a lot of them.

Comment: When you say `block the main thread` I assume you want to block the UI thread, which I don't think is a good idea(it may throw exceptions). Why don't you try using `AsyncTask` and show a progress dialog while you are fetching your data.

Comment: I don't want to block UI thread. I do not have UI at all in this application.
From the service I spawn few threads for each task (I previously called it main thread. I want to do not end them until their children threads are still working.

Comment: @Paweł did you get a chance to look at the edited code? If yes, was your issue resolved?

Comment: thanks you for the code. Now I am testing on several devices implementation with TimerTask. It works fine for about 25 hours. If it will crash, I will introduce your solution and give you a feedback.

Comment: timeout in my code was introduced in order to avoid stuck/freeze on some operation. For example reading from InputStream. Your code is iterating over the loop and checking the condition. If it is true it will throw exception but it can even do not reach this part of code. Therefore your solutions does not fit to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long TIMEOUT=100;
    Thread runner = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               for(;;){
                   System.out.println("running ");
               }

           }
               // some actions here
        });

    runner.start();
    long startJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    runner.join(TIMEOUT);
    long stopJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((stopJoin - startJoin) >= TIMEOUT)
        try {
            throw new Exception("Timeout when reading the response from   process");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Running Thread");

}
```

This program never ends that means your logic is incorrect.

Better to use `TimerTask`.

Comment: So maybe explain me where my logic is incorrect? If join method is working fine, this program should end.
I explained why I do not want to use TimerTask in comment to the answer above.

Comment: The exception is thrown, so why is it incorrect? The process doesn't end, because there's still a thread running..